# Upgrading to SQL vs. Improving Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, upgrade

Our firm has a rather complex proprietary Access database system including 15 or so unique front end modules that all perform different tasks and a backend database for each of our clients. All of these front end modules and backend databases have many SQL queries, functions, macros, and VBA code. We are considering upgrading to SQL Server or an equivalent but I see several major pitfalls including the incompatibility with VBA and Access functions. Do you think it would make more sense to stay with Access and look into improving via 1. accde/mde or accdr/mdr 2. split databases and/or 3. merging/consolidating front end modules? Do some of you have experience with such an upgrade or have any other recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

You should consider migrating tables to SQL Server and keeping the Access Front-end.  [SSMA For Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255) will move the data and replace the tables with ODBC linked tables for you.

Then, moving forward, you can continue to use Access or build applications using other tools.

Comment: That is certainly an interesting solution and tool. I will look into and test that out.

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that you run front ends with linked tables to the back end accDB file.

You then can migrate that database to sql server, you migrate only the data part.

The access FE (front end) should work as before - about 99% of the code and forms will work as before, but some tweaks are often required. Given that SQL express is free, then it is great setup and will allow you to keep and preserve most of your existing software investment

However, on each workstation, you are placing a FE of the application on that workstation. You as a general rule can't allow multiple users into the same given FE - it is to be placed on each workstation.

Comment: Our current setup does have some minimal overlap in usage of front end modules, but it's typically for the reporting type modules and not the processing/editing type modules. I'm sure it's based on the module-specific code, but some of the modules do have issues if more than 1 person is in it. Will that change with the migration to be even more multiple user unfriendly?

Comment: Well, as noted, I am suggesting that you gain, have, learn, and practice the concept of a split database. It is standard fair. And THEN when you decide to migrate to sql server, you will be in much better shape and on much familiar grounds as to how this setup works. So doing this the right way with Access + access back end and linked tables? Well, then when you go to sql server, the process will be far more seamless, and multi-user support will be much better (in fact it much better in both cases with a split system, and moving to sql server is not a requirement for running a split system).

Comment: Yes, that is one scenario I have been considering so your comment is helpful - I appreciate the detail.